# setting default host address for mongo client

Tags: mongodb

Each time I connect to a remote mongodb server, it is needed to write the host address of the mongo server.

In my situation, I connect only a single remote mongo. So, is there a way to set the default server address that make it possible to connect without passing host parameter each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a *nix os you can use `alias` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)):

```
alias mongo='mongo --host 127.0.0.1'
```

You might want to call you alias something else than `mongo` though.

Answer (score 2):

For the php driver, I can change the directive 'mongo.default_host = localhost' to 'mogno.default_host = REMOTEADDRESS'. By this change I no longer need to pass the host address. This is what I was looking for.